# Inserting alphanumeric characters into ms-access database using asp classic

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

I am having trouble when I try to introduce alphanumeric characters into ms-access database. I am able to do it with numerical and date characters, but it seems to be a problem with alphanumerical ones,

Here is the code I use:

```
Dim adoCon         
Dim strSQL        

Set adoCon=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")


adoCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("basededades.mdb")


'Here I am getting all the values previously passed by a form.

stringEntrada=Request.Form("stringEntrada")
stringSortida=Request.Form("stringSortida")
valoridHabitaciolliure=Request.Form("valoridHabitaciolliure")
numeropersones=Request.Form("numeroPersones")
nom=Request.Form("nom")
dni=Request.Form("dni")
tlf=Request.Form("tlf")
mail=Request.Form("mail")
ciutat=Request.Form("ciutat")
tipusH=Request.Form("tipusH")
diaReserva=Request.Form("diaReserva")
```

mail,nom,ciutat,tipusH,dni,valoridHabitaciolliure are alphanumerical characters from a text input form.
diaReserva,stringSortida,stringEntrada, are dates form a text input form.
tlf is a integer variable.

```
strSQL="INSERT INTO Reserva (dni,tlf,diaReserva,inici,fi,tipusHabitacio) VALUES ("&dni&","&tlf&",'"&diaReserva&"','"&stringEntrada&"','"&stringSortida&"'," "&tipusH&")" 
adoCon.Execute(strSQL)
```

When I see the values inserted into the database I realise that the date variables like "diaReserva" or "stringSortida" and the numerical ones like "tlf" are inserted correctly.

To insert date variables I use a simple ' surrounded by double " in the sql query: '"&stringEntrada&"'

To insert numerical ones I only use the double: "&tlf&"

If I try to use simple ' when I am trying to insert an alphanumerical, like: '"mail"' I do not recieve any error, but the database records a blank value.

If I try to use double ", like: "mail" I am getting an error.

How I could insert alphanumerical variables without having trouble?

Thank you for your time, and sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid your "quoting problem" and also avoid **SQL Injection** vulnerabilities by using a *parameterized query* similar to this one:

```
Dim con  '' As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd  '' As ADODB.Command
Dim stringName, longSponsorID, datetimeDateJoined

Const adCmdText = 1
Const adVarWChar = 202, adInteger = 3, adDate = 7
Const adParamInput = 1

'' test data
stringName = "Gord"
longSponsorID = 5
datetimeDateJoined = Now

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Public\mdbTest.mdb;"
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandText = _
        "INSERT INTO Members " & _
            "(memberName, sponsorID, dateJoined) " & _
        "VALUES " & _
            "(?, ?, ?)"
'' parameter for [memberName]
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255, stringName)
'' parameter for [sponsorID]
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adInteger, adParamInput, , longSponsorID)
'' parameter for [dateJoined]
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("?", adDate, adParamInput, , datetimeDateJoined)
cmd.Execute
Set cmd = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank your for your quick reply, unfortunatelly, it seems that does not work, I am having the same problem, the Integers values are added correctly and without problems. The problem persists with the string values, the instrucion does not return any error but when I inspect the database I see that there is not any value in the string column... that is wierd.

Comment: @MatiesPons To test your code, try to INSERT a record that contains fixed values (like `"testing"`) instead of the values from `Request.Form()`. If that still doesn't work then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16664339/edit) your question to add the new code you are using.

Comment: Ok, there is not any problem to enter predefined variables into my database, here is the proof: [link](http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/616/profiz.jpg)

So, it seems that the problem is when I parse the values from the previus form. Any idea how can i fix that?

Comment: @MatiesPons Okay that's good, at least the database part is working. So now you need to check your code to see if `mail=Request.Form("mail")` is actually returning anything. It has been a *long* time since I've done any Classic ASP, so all I can suggest is to perhaps try things like `Request.Form("mail").Text` or `Request.Form("mail").Value` to see if they work better.

Comment: Request.form("mail"). value/Text returns an error ("the object can not accept this property or method"). 
If I do a response.write("mail"), it returns de correct value, so I am confused about what is going wrong.

Comment: @MatiesPons Just a shot in the dark, but does `mail = CStr(Request.Form("mail"))` work any better?

Comment: Ok, I have found the source of the problems. The form that I used to pass the values was a bit special. All the input types where "hidden types" because I do not want that the user notice this values. If I change to  

<input name="mail" value="
 <%
 response.write(mail) 
 %>
 ">

All the problems where gone... The problem is that i do not want to be public this variables, so I have a partial solution ;)